# Common tabBar in specific components react-native-router-flux & react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have different views in my app, Three of them are linked to the TabBar like this: 
menu.js

`

```
<ScrollableTabView
      style={{marginTop: 0, borderWidth:1 }}
      tabBarPosition='bottom'
      scrollWithoutAnimation={true}
      initialPage={0}
      locked={true}
       ref={(tabView) => { this.tabView = tabView; }}
      renderTabBar={() => <UbicalaTabBar />}
    >
      <View tabLabel="database" style={{flex: 1}}>
          <MLS />
      </View>
      <View tabLabel="apartment" style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Inmuebles/>
      </View>
    {/*
      <View tabLabel="bubbles" style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Chat/>
      </View>
      */}
      <View tabLabel="icons2" style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Menu_Main />
      </View>
    </ScrollableTabView>
```

`

Here's an example of the TabBar:
[tabBarExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqlx6.png)

when I press the "Requerimientos" touchableHighlight it calls the "Requerimientos" View but the tabBar dissapears.
Here's a screenshot of the issue:
[IssueExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOOpq.png)

how could I make the TabBar static?, I want it to show in the different views or componentes that I have anywhere out the tabBar elements.

Requerimientos.js

```js
   <View>
               <Spinner 
        
       textContent={"Cargando..."} 
       overlayColor={"rgba(8, 34, 58,0.5)"}
       textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />

        <StatusBar
         barStyle="light-content"
         hidden={false}
       />
        
          {/*
            ESTA ES LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION
          */}
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{Actions.menu() }}>
              <View style={styles.nav_bar}  >
                    <Text style={styles.child1}><Text style={styles.texto_nav}>Mis Requerimientos</Text></Text>
              </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

      {/*
          ESTA ES LA DEL BOTON NUEVO INMUEBLE
      */}
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> Actions.modal_nuevoInmueble() }>
          <View style={styles.nav_boton_nuevoInmueble} >
              <Icon name={'star'} size={22} color={'white'} style={styles.icono_inmueble}/>
              <View style={{paddingLeft:15}}><Text style={styles.text_nav_boton_nuevoInmueble}>Nuevo Requerimiento</Text></View>
          </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>

         {/*
            ESTA ES LA DE BOTONES
          */}
         <View style={styles.nav_botones}>
         
          
          <ScrollableTabView
            style={{marginTop: 0,borderTopWidth:1,
          borderTopColor:'#e8e8eb'}}
            renderTabBar={()=><CaracteristicasTab backgroundColor='#f3f3f5'/>}
            tabBarPosition='overlayTop'
            tabBarBackgroundColor='white'>

    <View tabLabel='Mis Requerimientos' style={{marginTop:40, height:width.height-200}}>
     <ScrollView ref={(ref) => this.myScroll = ref} style={styles.container_inmuebles} scrollEventThrottle={16}  onScroll={(e)=>{
                              var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
                                height = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
                                offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

                             if (this.state.misRequerimientos.length<31) {scrollEnabled=false}
                              else if( (windowHeight + offset >= height) && bandera_scroll!==1 ){
                              // console.log("CArgando")
                              scrollEnabled=false;
                                 this.pintarResultadosPagina(offset)
                            }else{
                              scrollEnabled= false;
                            }
                            


                        }}>
              <View style={styles.separador_cantidad} >
                  <Text style={styles.texto_cantidad}>{this.state.texto_cantidad}</Text>
                </View>


 {  
                      this.state.misRequerimientos.map((item,index)=>{
                       
                       var result= item;
                       // console.log(result)
                      
                       var cuartos=0;
                       var banos=0;
                       var garajes=0;



                       if (result.cuartos=="" || result.cuartos==null || result.cuartos==undefined   ) {
                        result.cuartos =cuartos

                       }
                       if (result.banos=="" || result.banos==null || result.banos==undefined   ) {
                        result.banos =banos

                       }
                       if (result.garages=="" || result.garages==null || result.garages==undefined   ) {
                        result.garages =garajes

                       }

                       

                        if (typeof result=="string") {
                          return(<View key={index} style={{alignItems:'center',marginTop:0,borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor:'#e8e8eb'}}>
                                    <Image style={styles.catimg2} source={require("../images/app-bg.png")} />
                                      </View>)
                        }

                       

                        
                            if(result.precio=="" || result.precio==null || result.precio==undefined){
                              var precioMinimo = "$0"
                            }else{
                              var precioMinimo = "$"+parseInt(result.precio).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            }
                          
                            if(result.precio_maximo=="" || result.precio_maximo==null || result.precio_maximo==undefined){
                              var precioMaximo = "$0"
                            }else{
                              var precioMaximo = "$"+parseInt(result.precio_maximo).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            }
                         
                        return <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={()=>{ Actions.detalle_misRequerimientos(result._id.$id)}}>    
                                  <Grid style={styles.grid_inmueble}>
                                      
                                      <Col size={colText} style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >Cod. Requerimiento: <Text style={{color:'#596471',fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}} >{result.codigo_requerimiento}</Text> </Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >{(result.barrio +", "+result.ciudad)}</Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}]} >{result.inmueble}</Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >{"Precio mínimo"}: 
                                            <Text style={{color:'#008dde',fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}} >{" "+precioMinimo} </Text> </Text>
                                          </Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >{"Precio máximo"}: 
                                            <Text style={{color:'#008dde',fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}} >{" "+precioMaximo} </Text> </Text>
                                          </Row>
                                          <Row><Text ></Text></Row>
                                          <Row>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}]} ><Icon name={'crop'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.area}m²</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'bed'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.cuartos}</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'bathtub'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.banos}</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'car2'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.garages}</Text>

                                          </Row>
                                      </Col>
                                  </Grid>
                              </TouchableOpacity>

                            //this.renderResult(item);
                          })}

                      {/*<ListView
                                              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                                              renderRow={(rowData) =>{ return this.renderResult(rowData) }  }
                                             pageSize={100}
                                          /> */ }
              

                      <View style={styles.separador_cargar} >
                        <Text style={styles.texto_cargar}>{this.state.texto_cargar}</Text>
                      </View>
         </ScrollView>
         </View>
      <View tabLabel='Favoritos' style={{marginTop:40, height:width.height-200}}>
    {/*
     <ScrollView ref={(ref2) => this.myScroll = ref2} style={styles.container_inmuebles} scrollEventThrottle={5000}  onScroll={(e)=>{
                              var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
                                height = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
                                offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;


                            if( (windowHeight + offset >= height) && bandera_scroll!==1 ){
                              // console.log("CArgando")

                                 
                               if (this.state.misInmueblesFavoritos.length-1 < 30) {
                                  scrollEnabled= false;
                                  this.setState({texto_cargarFavoritos:"No hay más favoritos"})
                               }else{
                                  this.pintarResultadosPaginaFavoritos(offset)
                                  scrollEnabled=true;
                               }
                            }else{
                              scrollEnabled= false;
                            }


                        }}>
              <View style={styles.separador_cantidad} >
                  <Text style={styles.texto_cantidad}>{this.state.texto_cantidadFavoritos}</Text>
                </View>

 {                
                      this.state.misInmueblesFavoritos.map((item,index)=>{
                       var result= item;
                       var cuartos=0;
                       var banos=0;
                       var garajes=0;


                       if (result.cuartos=="" || result.cuartos==null || result.cuartos==undefined   ) {
                        result.cuartos =cuartos

                       }
                       if (result.banos=="" || result.banos==null || result.banos==undefined   ) {
                        result.banos =banos

                       }
                       if (result.garages=="" || result.garages==null || result.garages==undefined   ) {
                        result.garages =garajes

                       }

                       global.idFavorito= 0

                       // console.log(result)
                        if (typeof result=="string") {
                          return(<View key={index} style={{alignItems:'center',marginTop:0,borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor:'#e8e8eb'}}>
                                    <Image style={styles.catimg2} source={require("../images/app-bg.png")} />
                                      </View>)
                        }

                        var imagen_placeholder;
                         if (result.imagen !== "") {

                           var t_img = result.imagen.replace('http://','https://')
                          imagen_placeholder={uri:t_img};
                        }else{
                            imagen_placeholder=require("../images/Imagen_no_disponible.png");
                        }
                        if (result.imagen=="-large") {
                          imagen_placeholder=require("../images/Imagen_no_disponible.png");
                        }

                        
                        if (result.transaccion_inmueble) {

                          if (result.transaccion_inmueble=="Venta") {
                            var precio = "$"+parseInt(result.precio_venta).toLocaleString()
                          }else{
                            var precio = "$"+parseInt(result.precio_renta).toLocaleString()
                          }
                        }

                        return <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={()=> {Actions.detalle_misInmuebles(result._id.$id),banderaDesdeFavoritos=1, idFavorito=result.id_favorito}}>    
                                  <Grid style={styles.grid_inmueble}>
                                     <Col size={colImagen} style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                                        <Image style={styles.catimg} source={imagen_placeholder} />
                                      </Col>
                                      <Col size={colText} style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >Cod. Inmueble: <Text style={{color:'#596471',fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}} >{result.requerimiento}</Text> </Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >{(result.barrio +", "+result.ciudad)}</Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}]} >{result.inmueble}</Text></Row>
                                          <Row><Text style={styles.txt_inmueble} >{result.transaccion_inmueble}: 
                                            <Text style={{color:'#008dde',fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}} >{" "+precio} </Text> </Text>
                                          </Row>
                                          <Row><Text ></Text></Row>
                                          <Row>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold'}]} ><Icon name={'crop'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.area}m</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'bed'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.cuartos}</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'bathtub'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.banos}</Text>
                                               <Text style={[styles.txt_inmueble,{fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Bold',marginLeft:10}]} ><Icon name={'car2'}
                                                    size={15}
                                                    color={'#596471'}
                                                    style={{marginLeft:10}}
                                                  />{result.garages}</Text>

                                          </Row>
                                      </Col>
                                  </Grid>
                              </TouchableOpacity>

                            //this.renderResult(item);
                          })}
                */}
                      {/*<ListView
                                              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                                              renderRow={(rowData) =>{ return this.renderResult(rowData) }  }
                                             pageSize={100}
                                          /> */ }
              

                      <View style={styles.separador_cargar} >
                        <Text style={styles.texto_cargar}>{this.state.texto_cargarFavoritos}</Text>
                      </View>
         {/*</ScrollView>*/}

         

         </View>
      
    </ScrollableTabView>

{/*

    <Router>
        
          <Scene
            key="menu"
            component={Menu}
            hideNavBar={true}
            title="Menu"
           initial
            
          />
          
      </Router>

      */}

        </View>
       <DropdownAlert
              ref={(ref) => this.dropdown = ref}
              titleNumOfLines={0}
              messageNumOfLines={0}
              closeInterval={1800}
              containerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#08223a',
              }}
              showCancel={false}
            />

        </View>
        
    );
  }
  
}
```

ubicalaTabBar.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
//import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/UbicalaIcons';

const UbicalaTabBar = React.createClass({
  tabIcons: [],

  propTypes: {
    goToPage: React.PropTypes.func,
    activeTab: React.PropTypes.number,
    tabs: React.PropTypes.array,
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this._listener = this.props.scrollValue.addListener(this.setAnimationValue);
  },

  setAnimationValue({ value, }) {
    this.tabIcons.forEach((icon, i) => {
      const progress = Math.min(1, Math.abs(value - i))
      icon.setNativeProps({
        style_button: {
          color: this.iconColor(progress),
        }
      });
    });
  },

  //color between rgb(59,89,152) and rgb(204,204,204)
  iconColor(progress) {
    const red = 0 + (8 - 0) * progress;
    const green = 141 + (34 - 141) * progress;
    const blue = 222 + (58 - 222) * progress;
    return `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  },

  render() {
    //Menu perzonalizado para ubicala
  //  const menu = ["MLS","Inmuebles","Chat","Menu"]
    const menu = ["MLS","Inmuebles","Menu"]
    return <View style={[styles.tabs, this.props.style_button, ]}>
      {this.props.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity key={tab} onPress={() => this.props.goToPage(i)} style={styles.tab}>
          <Icon
            name={tab}
            icons={tab}
            height={30}
            size={22}
            color={this.props.activeTab === i ? 'rgb(0,141,222)' : 'rgb(8,34,58)'}
            ref={(icon) => { this.tabIcons[i] = icon; }}
          />
          <Text style={[styles.text_menu]}>{menu[i]}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>;
      })}
    </View>;
  },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tab: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  text_menu:{
    fontSize:10,
    marginTop:5,
    fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Light',
    color:'#596471'
  },
  tabs: {
    height: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor:'#f3f3f5',
    paddingTop: 15,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor:'#d6d6d8',
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
  },
});

export default UbicalaTabBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to  remake the scenes and convert them into nested scenes

```
 <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true}  >
                    <Scene
            key="main"
            tabs
            tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}
            tabBarSelectedItemStyle={styles.tabBarSelectedItemStyle}
            hideNavBar={true}
          >
            <Scene
              key="tab1"
              title="MLS"
              iconName='database'
              icon={TabIcon}
              initial
              hideNavBar={true}
            >
              <Scene
                key="tab1_1"
                component={MLS}
                title="Tab #1_1"
                hideNavBar={true}
              />
              <Scene
                key="filtrar_busquedar"
                component={FiltrarBusqueda}
                hideNavBar={true}
                hideTabBar={true}
                title="FiltrarBusqueda"


              /> 
               <Scene
                  direction="horizontal"
                  key="detalle_inmueble"
                  component={DetalleInmueble}
                  hideNavBar={true}
                  title="DetalleInmueble"

                />


            </Scene>
            <Scene key="tab2"  title="Inmuebles" iconName='apartment' icon={TabIcon}>
              <Scene
                key="tab2_1"
                component={Inmuebles}
                title="Tab #2_1"
               hideNavBar={true}
              />

            </Scene>
            <Scene key="tab3" title="Menú" iconName='icons2' icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar={true} >
                <Scene
                    key="tab3_1"
                    component={Menu_Main}
                    title="Tab #3_1"
                    hideNavBar={true}
                    renderRightButton={() => <Text>Right</Text>}
                 />
                 <Scene
                    key="tab3_2"
                    component={Requerimientos}
                    title="Tab #3_2"
                    hideNavBar={true}
                    renderRightButton={() => <Text>Right</Text>}
                 />
            </Scene>
```